# Consolidate CSS using gulp

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp

I bought a bootstrap theme from an external vendor and have modified it according to my company needs. This theme uses multiple css files and when I test the webpage using coverage option in google chrome developer console, most of the css rules don't even apply to the pages. I'm looking a way to identify unused CSS rules and consolidate all the css to one or two css files with only applicable rules. Since I have multiple pages on my website, I'm looking for an automatic way to create this using Gulp or any other libraries[image].

Comment: bootstrap scss/less have separate files for different components.when you download you can choose what to download.fo example you can just download gridsystem without anything else.so may be you can do the same with your theme.check the file structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gulp module to figure out what CSS is not used

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-purgecss

Once you have your CSS tidied up, you should concatenate all your files (merge together for less requests) and minify them (reduce spaces and line breaks making less work for the computer to interpret)

A simple search on NPM should show you the best modules and how to implement.